# HTML DIV height conflict

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside my html body, and the div properties is declared this way in css:

```css
#container {
    width: auto;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I tried all height values and none worked as I wanted to. The problem is, I'm doing some query to display results inside this div. Sometimes I'll have just 1 result, another time 50. And here comes the problem. When I have only 1, the div goes up and shows the page background (behind the div) while I want it to be white and occupying the entire height even with 1 result only. Other times, when I get 50, the scrollbar of the page, do not get big enough to roll the entire div, and the informations get inside the bottom side of the div without the possibility to read them. If I get the height working for one case, it screw up the another. How to get both things working?
My html page where the div is:

```
<body id="home">
    <div id="container">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['news']))
            {
                include 'news.php';         
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

The news.php is where I make the query to display the thing on the div.

Comment: Try `overflow: auto;` in your css.  That will put a scrollbar on your div when you need one and hide it when you don't.

Comment: This way I get 2 scroll bars.. What I think is not interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you need is:

`#container {
      width: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

the point is the overflow to scroll
    #container {
    width: auto;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

Comment: The problem is that this way I get 2 scrolls (one for the page, another for the div)... If I use the height as 'auto' for example, it uses only one scroll (from the page), but when the div have little results, it get too small showing the background of the page behind it.

Comment: can't you try as sticky footer works, you want to grow the div depending of the data in include?

Comment: No, I want the div to always occupy the entire height of the page, even when it query result return only 1. And in the same time I want the div to work with the scroll bar of the page, when the query return many results...

Comment: ok then, <div style="min-height: [your minimun height]"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can always explicitly set the height of the html tag to 100% in the CSS and then set your container class to whatever percentage of the screen you would like it to fill. It *should* always be that percentage.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got your idea... Can you show the example please?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

if you want your #container to always stick to the bottom of the page, then use this:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Creating a fiddle could have helped.